# Delete a document from DocumentDb

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to delete a specific document from my DocumentDb collection called Employees. When I run the following code, I get "A task was cancelled" error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private async static void RemoveEmployeeAsync(string colSelfLink)
        {
            var doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(colSelfLink, "SELECT * FROM Employees e WHERE e.EmployeeId = 1").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

            if(doc != null)
            {
                await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably due to your use of `async void`. Probably whatever is calling this code is disposing some managing resource (i.e., `client`) before `RemoveEmployeeAsync` completes.

The best solution is to make `RemoveEmployeeAsync` return a `Task` instead of `void`, and have the calling code `await` it.